# PowerShell & FileNotFoundException : which file?

Tags: powershell, windows-sbs

I'm trying to follow the instructions in http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg697165.aspx, but my powershell script keeps throwing exceptions. It refers to a FileNotFoundException...but I can't figure out which file it can't find.

Does anyone have any hands on experience with this?

```
C:\Program Files\Windows Server\Bin>powershell .\ConfigureRDP.ps1
Exception calling "RunTasks" with "2" argument(s): "IWorkerConfig.dll"
At C:\Program Files\Windows Server\Bin\ConfigureRDP.ps1:3 char:1
+ $scheduler.RunTasks("ConfigureRDPTaskList", "ConfigureRDPTaskStatus.xml") | out- ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileNotFoundException

The configuration is complete. Check file "  " for result.

C:\Program Files\Windows Server\Bin>
```

Comment: Is "ConfigureRDPTaskStatus.xml" in the same directory where you running ConfigureRDP.ps1?

Comment: Hi, I think that file should be created. According to the documentation (the KB article), it should contain the result of the RunTasks command. I do suspect it is the IWorkerConfig.dll...its not in The file IWorkerConfig.dll is not in the C:\Program Files\Windows Server\Bin.

Comment: I think you are right. The script needs to be run from within the directory where IWorkerConfig.dll exists.

Comment: Hmmm...but where is the IWorkerConfig.dll file located then?